# How can I fix 'higher version' error with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData when implementing OData in Azure Function with Http Trigger?

Tags: azure-functions, odata

I am trying to implement OData for an Azure Function with Http Trigger. I have added Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData nuget package to the application. I see the following error

> Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, Version=8.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

I am not able to find the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package with version 6.0.0.0. No clue what this error is.

Does anyone has solution for this?

I tried find the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package with version 6.0.0.0. It looks this part of .Net6.0. I am using the visual 2022 with >net 6.0 version.

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question, it will help us to know why the error occurs.

Comment: Hey @KishoreCheryala, Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Provide the minimal functionality or the packages you're using with their versions (.cs proj) so we can check the related/compatible versioned packages and could provide the solution. Otherwise, moderators will close the questions within 48hours as if question miss details.

Comment: This issue is resolved using the following post.


https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/504


add the following tag in .csproj file.


<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved using the following post. [github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/504](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/504)

add the following tag in .csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup> <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> </ItemGroup>
```